# ARM doesn't generate unaligned exception

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-kernel, arm, memory-alignment

Here's my code:

```
 char data[5]  = {0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5 };
 int *ptr = (int *)(data + 1);
 int value = *ptr;

 printf("address of data= %lu\n",data);
 printf("address of data +1 = %lu\n",data+1);
```

When I compile using gcc -Wcast-align for ARM, it emits the warning "cast increases required alignment of target type".

But when I run it on the ARM processor, it **doesn't generate misaligned access exception**.

The printf showed that data is located at an address that is a multiple of 4 and hence data+1 is an odd address which should generate an unaligned exception.

I set /proc/cpu/alignment to 3.  Didn't get any message in dmesg.

Why am I not getting the exception?

Comment: What are you doing to make sure that data array aligns at an address which is a multiple of 4 ? What is the actual address of data array when you inspect while debugging ? Which ARM CPU ?

Comment: It's arm version 7.  Let me edit the question to print the address of data.

Comment: just because arm (mips, etc) historically discourage and fault on unaligned transfers doesnt mean you will always see that, you can disable the event, and depending on the core the data returned from the unaligned transfer is determnistic (the newer cores are more like what a programmer would expect).  the performance penalty is naturally there just like an x86...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where the ARMv6+ unaligned access model is in force, the kernel [always clears the SCTLR.A bit](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/mm/alignment.c#L967) (note the `if (cpu_is_v6_unaligned())...` part) since in practice there's little point in raising exceptions for things that will work just fine in hardware. You'll only get exceptions for instructions which are entirely invalid if unaligned, like LDM/STM.

Comment: Easily confirmed by `cat /proc/cpu/alignment`.  If the *User* count doesn't increase with a stock kernel, then it is not happening.

Answer (score 3):

1: Maybe the kernel always allows unaligned access for data types <= 32 bits and ignores your /proc setting.

2: Have you checked the assembly code generated ? The compiler may have optimized away the ptr variable and just memcpy'ed the 4 bytes from &data[1] to &value. This way you can never get the exception regardless of the setting. ARM compiler did this for Cortex-M3 target when it detected the unaligned access !

Comment: The second point also bears true in another context - anything that could cause an unaligned access would be undefined behaviour in C, thus the compiler is perfectly at liberty to simply not generate any code that would do so.